# The probability distribution of a discrete random variable-Finding Fx

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

The probability distribution of a discrete random variable "X" is given below:

Value x of X:  P(X=x)

```
-5      :  0.24
-4      :  0.16
-3      :  0.17
-2      :  0.15
-1      :  0.28
```

Let Fx
be the cumulative distribution function of
. Compute the following:

Fx(-2)=

Fx(-1)-Fx(-4)=

Fx(-16/5)=

My answer

$Fx(-2)= 0.24+0.16+0.17+0.15= 0.72$

$Fx(-1)-Fx(-4)= 0.28+0.15+0.17+0.16= 0.76$

$Fx(-16/5)= 0.24+0.16=0.4$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $$Fx(-2) = 0.72$$
I believe $$Fx(-1) - Fx(-4) =  [0.24 + 0.16 + 0.17 + 0.15 + 0.28] - [0.24 + 0.16] = 0.17 + 0.15 + 0.28 = 0.60$$
Alternatively we could solve $Fx(-1) - Fx(-4) = 1 - 0.4 = 0.6$.

And you are correct that $$Fx(-16/5) = Fx(-3.2) = 0.24 + 0.16 = 0.4$$
since -3.2 < -3 and we only have probability mass at negative integers.

Comment: Isn't it $$Fx(-1)-F(-4)= P(X<=-1)-P(X<=-4)= P(-4<=X<=-1)= 0.28+0.15+0.17+0.16=0.76$$

Comment: $Fx(−1) − F(−4) = P(X<=−1) − P(X<=−4) = P(−4<X<=−1)$ where X lies in a semi-closed interval (-4,-1] and -4 is not included

Comment: For discrete random variable X, for all a <= b, P(a < X <= b) = F(b) - F(a). Proof: for a <= b, P(X <= b) = P(X <= a) + P(a < X <= b). Thus F(b) = F(a) + P(a < X <= b).Subtract F(a) from both sides and P(a < X <= b)  = F(b) - F(a).// This can be confusing with discrete random variables as there is a difference between P(X <= x) = F(x) and P(X < x).

Comment: There is another proof to that P(a < X <= b) = F(b) - F(a), however, that uses sample spaces and is slightly more wordy for my taste.

Comment: Understood, Thanks a lot